# How to dynamically import javascript and css files

Tags: java, javascript, css, jsp, servlets

i Want to import a given css or javascript file depending os some conditions, in my Servlet i have:

```
protected void doPost(...)
{
   if(condition)
   {
     //import some javascript or css file here
   }

}
```

I need this behavior since i have too many files to import and the files name may vary according to the condition.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of, yes.

```
boolean condition = evaluateItSomehow();
request.setAttribute("condition", condition);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Then in `page.jsp` using [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) `c:if`:

```
<head>
    <c:if test="${condition}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </c:if>
    ...
</head>
```

**Update:** since you seem to have more than one files for this, you can even make it more flexible by just setting the desired filename suffix (or prefix, or even the entire name, what you like):

```
String suffix = evaluateItSomehow();
request.setAttribute("suffix", suffix);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

and

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_${suffix}.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script_${suffix}.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
```

If you set `suffix` to for example `"foo"`, this will load `style_foo.css` and `script_foo.js`. I think this gives enough new insights.

Comment: hello :) is there any problem with the bwoser cache when using this method? if i want to load same page, on different conditions, using many kinds of css? wil the client browser cache the css?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to insert Javascript and CSS into the dom? I would do that from the client side. I mean, it is *possible* to do it by explicitly writing out the code for `<script...>` or `<link...>`. A better way to do it is to send something back to the client that tells it to add a stylesheet or Javascript.

Then you can add it dynamically like so:

- [Dynamically inserting Javascript and CSS (without jQuery)](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Howto_Dynamically_Insert_Javascript_And_CSS)
- [Dynamically inserting Javascript and CSS (with jQuery)](http://topsecretproject.finitestatemachine.com/2009/09/how-to-load-javascript-and-css-dynamically-with-jquery/)

If this doesn't need to be done dynamically, then it is even easier. Simply set a flag and in your JSP or ASP, check the state of the flag. Within the conditional tag, you will add the code for your CSS and Javascript. However, I am assuming from your question that it is the former.

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype) {
            if (filetype == "js") { //if filename is a external JavaScript file
               // alert('called');
                var fileref = document.createElement('script')
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
                fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
                alert('called');
            }
            else if (filetype == "css") { //if filename is an external CSS file
                var fileref = document.createElement("link")
                fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
                fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
            }
            if (typeof fileref != "undefined")
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
        }
```

Call this javascript function to dynamically load the css and js file. Pass the complete file path with name in ‘filename’ argument.